# ASP.NET MVC 3 Binding Unsuccessful

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble making my ASP.NET MVC 3 View bind data back to a Model.

The typical objects such as `string ContactName` and `string Title` are being sent back successfully.

My `public List<KeyValuePair<string, ListingTranslation>> ExpirimentToRemove` object however isn't being sent back for some reason.

The following is contains code of the specific objects that aren't being binded successfully.

```
<div>
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExpirimentToRemove.Count; i++)
        {
           <li class="@i == 0 ? 'active' : ''"><a href="#@Model.Translations.Keys.ToList()[i]" data-toggle="tab">@Model.Translations.Keys.ToList()[i]</a></li>
        }
     </ul>
     <div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExpirimentToRemove.Count; i++)
         {
             <div class="tab-pane@i == 0 ? ' active' : ''" id="@@Model.Translations.Keys.ToList()[i]">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.Title)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.FullDescription)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ExpirimentToRemove[i].Value.PreviewDescription)
             </div>
          }
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for a list of items to be bound back is to have hidden fields.

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) is a great article explaining it in detail

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
<input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
<input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />
```

The only other way is to manually manipulate the name attribute for the element that corresponds with the object path for the given item in `List<T>`.

Comment: I'll try that now! Thank you! Stay tuned please!